# flume taking time to copy data into hdfs when rolling based on file size

Tags: hadoop, flume

I have a usecase where i want to copy remote file into hdfs using flume. I also want that the copied files should align with the HDFS block size (128MB/256MB).Total size of remote data is 33GB.

I am using avro source and sink to copy remote data into hdfs. Similarly from sink side i am doing file size rolling(128,256).but for copying file from remote machine and storing it  into hdfs(file size 128/256 MB) flume is taking an avg of 2 min.

Flume Configuration:
Avro Source(Remote Machine)

```
### Agent1 - Spooling Directory Source and File Channel, Avro Sink  ###
# Name the components on this agent
Agent1.sources = spooldir-source  
Agent1.channels = file-channel
Agent1.sinks = avro-sink

# Describe/configure Source
Agent1.sources.spooldir-source.type = spooldir
Agent1.sources.spooldir-source.spoolDir =/home/Benchmarking_Simulation/test


# Describe the sink
Agent1.sinks.avro-sink.type = avro
Agent1.sinks.avro-sink.hostname = xx.xx.xx.xx   #IP Address destination machine
Agent1.sinks.avro-sink.port = 50000

#Use a channel which buffers events in file
Agent1.channels.file-channel.type = file
Agent1.channels.file-channel.checkpointDir = /home/Flume_CheckPoint_Dir/
Agent1.channels.file-channel.dataDirs = /home/Flume_Data_Dir/
Agent1.channels.file-channel.capacity = 10000000
Agent1.channels.file-channel.transactionCapacity=50000

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
Agent1.sources.spooldir-source.channels = file-channel
Agent1.sinks.avro-sink.channel = file-channel
```

Avro Sink(Machine where hdfs running)

```
### Agent1 - Avro Source and File Channel, Avro Sink  ###
# Name the components on this agent
Agent1.sources = avro-source1  
Agent1.channels = file-channel1
Agent1.sinks = hdfs-sink1

# Describe/configure Source
Agent1.sources.avro-source1.type = avro
Agent1.sources.avro-source1.bind = xx.xx.xx.xx
Agent1.sources.avro-source1.port = 50000

# Describe the sink
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.type = hdfs
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.path =/user/Benchmarking_data/multiple_agent_parallel_1
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 130023424
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.batchSize = 50000
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.txnEventMax = 40000
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.threadsPoolSize=1000
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.appendTimeout = 10000
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.callTimeout = 200000


#Use a channel which buffers events in file
Agent1.channels.file-channel1.type = file
Agent1.channels.file-channel1.checkpointDir = /home/Flume_Check_Point_Dir
Agent1.channels.file-channel1.dataDirs = /home/Flume_Data_Dir
Agent1.channels.file-channel1.capacity = 100000000
Agent1.channels.file-channel1.transactionCapacity=100000


# Bind the source and sink to the channel
Agent1.sources.avro-source1.channels = file-channel1
Agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.channel = file-channel1
```

Network connectivity between both machine is 686 Mbps.

Can somebody please help me to identify whether something is wrong in the configuration or an alternate configuration so that the copying doesn't take so much of time.

Answer (score 1):

Both agents use file channel. So before writing to HDFS, data has been written to disk twice. You can try to use a memory channel for each agent to see if the performance is improved.

Comment: I try to use memory channel and see performance.I am using file channel because it is durable channel and i want to run this in production.

Comment: @mandar I'm afraid, if you use file channel, you have to face the performance decrease problem (compared to memory channel)